# OAUTH flow - Event Hub

Tags: azure, security, authentication, events

I have a Event Producer Client that will be outside of the AD Tenancy where the Event Hub queue exists.

Is this approach with Event Hub viewed as secure to be allowing the client to access my queue using OAUTH?

What OAUTH Flow would be most suited to this scenario?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by outside of the AD Tenancy...

Comment: The client will be developing an application that is not within my Azure tenancy.

Comment: The Client Credential Flow should suffice....in my opinion..